# Installing cx_Oracle on 64 bit windows

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, oracle10g, cx-oracle

I need to install cx_oracle on a Windows 7x64, Oracle 10g (32 bit).

What should be the version of

- Oracle Instant Client (i installed x64 bit)
- cx_Oracle binary (i installed x64 bit)
- Python 2.7.13 (i installed x64 bit)

There are version incompatibility issues which were expected. I am confused which version should i follow. Should i install 32 bit version of all the above three ?

**Error**

**cx_Oracle - DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application**

I have followed all the steps. Installed Oracle client first, set path and ORACLE_HOME to the C:\oracle\instant_client_10_2 and then installed cx_Oracle. What is the most painless way to successfully install it?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024016/how-do-i-get-cx-oracle-to-work-on-64-bit-itanium-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This issue possible solutions widely described on another SO [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159566/cx-oracle-importerror-dll-load-failed-this-application-has-failed).

But analyzing your message, I can suggest you to add your instant client folder (like ...\instantclient_12_1) to your PATH environment variable.

And if won't work, move this path at your first place in PATH's paths to test if smth overlap that.